# How will i join/combine these two table to get one result

Tags: sql, mysqli

Table 1

```
 Code    Name1        type  BalanceDue  id1   id2   id3   id4     id5    emp
 2600   intl-Airfare    1     2.38     120   410    510   603   7060513 null
 1100   intl-travel     1     2.66     120   420    540   602   7060513 null
 2400   intl-Meals      1     1.50     120   420    520   602   7060513 null
 4100   Transpo         2    19.70     110   210    510   601           null
 4100   Transpo         2    13.25     110   210    500   601           null
 4100   Transpo         2    17.38     110   210    500   600           null
 3600   Dom travel      3    25.11     110   210    500   600    55713  null
```

Table 2

```
 Code      Details            Total  type code1 code2   code3   code4    code5   emp
 4100   no#233 Emp1-Parking   11.39    2   110    210     510     601     null   null 
 4100   no#231 Jes-Parking     6.83    2   110    210     510     601     null   null
 4100   no#232 Jes-TransExp    1.48    2   110    210     510     601     null   null
 4100   no#234 Emp2-TollFee    0.23    2   110    210     500     601     null   null
 4100   no#239 Emp2-Parking    1.82    2   110    210     500     601     null   null
 4100   no#240 Emp3-Parking    2.96    2   110    210     500     601     null   null
 4100   no#252 Emp5-TollFee    8.24    2   110    210     500     601     null   null
 4100   no#235 Jay-TollFee     4.90    2   110    210     500     600     null   null
 4100   no#243 Jay-TransExp   12.48    2   110    210     500     600     null   null
```

I want this as a result:
if type is 1 then display all values in table 1 which has type 1
same as if type is 3
if type is 2 then display all values in table 2 considering code1 to code5

Result

```
Code    Details           type  Total  code1  code2  code3   code4    code5   emp 
 2600   intl-Airfare          1   2.38    120    410     510     603   7060513  null
 1100   intl-travel           1   2.66    120    420     540     602   7060513  null
 2400   intl-Meals            1   1.50    120    420     520     602   7060513  null
 4100   no#233 Emp1-Parking   2  11.39    110    210     510     601     null   null 
 4100   no#231 Jes-Parking    2  6.83     110    210     510     601     null   null
 4100   no#232 Jes-TransExp   2  1.48     110    210     510     601     null   null
 4100   no#234 Emp2-TollFee   2  0.23     110    210     500     601     null   null
 4100   no#239 Emp2-Parking   2  1.82     110    210     500     601     null   null
 4100   no#240 Emp3-Parking   2  2.96     110    210     500     601     null   null
 4100   no#252 Emp5-TollFee   2  8.24     110    210     500     601     null   null
 4100   no#235 Jay-TollFee    2  4.90     110    210     500     600     null   null
 4100   no#243 Jay-TransExp   2  12.48    110    210     500     600     null   null
 3600   Dom travel            3  25.11    110    210     500     600     55713  null
```

Sometimes, id5 has a value and sometimes other columns were null.
sorry, i hope i explained it clearly :(
Thanks everyone!

Comment: Your table 2 and result seems to be same by the way.

Comment: Your result looks to be identical to Table 2, so why do you need to join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired results look like a `UNION` (The `UNION` clause lets your "merge" together more queries in a single, final result set) similar to this:

```
SELECT  Code, Name1 as Details, type, BalanceDue as Total,id1 as code1, id2 as code2,
        id3 as code3, id4 as code4, id5 as code5, emp 
        FROM Table1 WHERE type IN (1, 3) -- could also be WHERE type = 1 OR type = 3
UNION
SELECT  Code, Details, type, Total, code1, code2, code3, code4, code5, emp 
        FROM Table2 WHERE type = 2
```